# Springboot JPA with Tomcat 7

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to deploy springboot with JPA on Tomcat 7.  The app works fine when running with java -jar.  But with deployed on Tomcat, it is often saying can't find the bean with extended JpaRepository interface.

What is the proper way to deploy springboot on Tomcat 7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using"?

Answer (score 0):

some times this will helps

in **Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

Add this **Dependency and Plugin** to `pom.xml`

```
<!--For Build War File-->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


       <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This works for me

Hope this will helps...!